# SyntaxError: JSON.parse в Firefox 60 ESR, Debian

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, fetch, symfony4

При помощи fetch получаю данные из контроллера. На самом деле не важно какие, главное что возвращаются они в json

```
$result = array("key" => "value");
return new JsonResponse($result);
```

И собственно

```
fetch(get_messages_count_url, {
   method: 'GET'
}).then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
   console.log(json);
}).catch(function(ex) {
   console.log(ex);
});
```

В консоли браузера Firefox 60 ESR на Debian выкидывает ошибку

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Во всех остальных браузерах (Firefox 67 Android, Chromium Debian, Chrome Android) всё отлично работает, ну то есть выкидывает в консоль json как и нужно.
Сначала грешил на настройки сервера на компе, оказалось только браузер подводит, чего не хотелось бы, так как юзеры могут и со старых браузеров заходить. Пробовал полифилы промисов использовать. Но в ходе изучения и испробования XMLHttpRequest, промисы и всё остальное вполне нормально работает. Аякс тоже работает, но почему-то дольше думает. Получается что браузер не справляется примерно в строке return response.json(). 
Что можно сделать чтоб работало в устаревших браузерах?

Контроллер [php на github](https://github.com/seandle/store/blob/master/src/Controller/DashboardInboxController.php) на строке 161, 
Фронт [js на github](https://github.com/seandle/store/blob/master/public/extras/javascript/main_dashboard.js) на строке110

Comment: По ошибке очевидно что JSON.parse не может распарсить ответ от сервера. Вы точно уверены что в ff на debian именно json прилетает?

Comment: @sneas а как проверить что прилетает? Потому что при console.log(response) выводится просто мета информация о передаче (url, http status...) и никаких данных о передаваемом json нет.

Comment: Сетевой монитор https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor . При помощи него можно убедиться что http запрос к серверу принимает именно json-строку, а не html или сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Проверить response.status. Получить reponse.text() и посмотреть на него глазами, прогнать через encodeURIComponent и посмотреть ещё раз.

Comment: @sneas благодарю Вас, помогло решить проблему. Пост нижу.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Для использования fetch в старых браузерах нужно

```
fetch(url, {
   credentails: 'same-origin'
});
```

Инструкции в [README к fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch). 
До этого контроллер возвращал отрицательный результат проверки авторизации в виде html, потому и была ошибка парсинга json. Готовый рабочий код будет в исходниках на github по ссылкам внизу в первом посте.